# Jtable with color and columns combined- merge columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtreetable

I have a table with combined columns for all the names of a company's accounts (see figure).
I want to configure the jtable to show the data as in the image. I have read about the table tree but I have not achieved the format of the figure.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozVw8.png]

Comment: `JTable` doesn't (easily) support "grouping".  One approach might be to use multiple tables and place them all within a single `JScrollPane` instead

Comment: Has the format of the table changed yet can I get it with Jtable?

Comment: No, not with a single `JTable`

Comment: What components do I need to get it? just a jscrollpane to contain the multiple tables?

Comment: You could get away with that.  You could also use a `JLabel` as the "primary" grouping header/seperator, depending on your overall needs